# SSRS 2008 value auto converted to date when downloading in csv

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm fixing the report in SSRS that download the file in CSV. The value is fine when downloading to EXCEL. This is the scenario: 1-1 become 1-Jan.

Anyone idea on this? Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify.  The value is '1-1' in EXCEL but '1-Jan' in CSV?  That is the other way round to what I can recreate.  What version of SSRS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Just in `CSV` file change the format of your column open your `CSV` file and select your column and right click it and then click on format the column and your first tab select `Date`and select the format of your `Date`

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be add a simple quotation mark (`'`) at the beginning of the field containing `1-1`.

You can do that by adding the following expression in the textbox where you are placing your field.

```
=& "'" & Fields!YourField.Value
```

It will produce the following value:

```
'1-1
```

> Excel will take your field as `1-1`. Howerver if you generate your
>   report in other formats your report will show your field as `'1-1`.

Let me know if this was helpful.